# prototype.js - IE8 - recursive function doesn't work after refresh

Tags: javascript, recursion, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I have this recursive function, where thumbs is array of IMG objects... Whole function works properly for me in Chrome, IE9, FF and so on, but freezes in IE8 after refreshing or navigating from site to site... When new tab is opened, all IMGs loads correctly, but after reload script "dies" without any sings of error...  The function is called from some 'init' function where thumbs array, filename etc. is to be initiated... appreciate your time guys...

```
function preload(thumbs) {
    last = thumbs[thumbs.length - 1];

    loadThumb(0);

    function loadThumb(th) {
        filename = thumbs[th].id.split('-')[1];
        thumbs[th].setAttribute('src', '/data/cache/thumb-' + filename + '.jpg');
        handle(th, thumbs);
        thumbs[th].observe('load', (function (event) {
            thumbs[th].setStyle({
                visibility: 'visible',
                opacity: 0.3
            });
            loadThumb(th + 1);
        }));
    }
};

last.observe('load', (function (event) {
    $('load').setStyle({
        visibility: 'hidden'
    });
    kar_width = last.positionedOffset();
    $('karusel').setStyle({
        width: kar_width[0] + last.getWidth() + 10 + 'px'
    });
    if ($('karusel').getWidth() < 700) {
        $('next').hide();
        $('prev').hide();
        $('next1').hide();
        $('prev1').hide();
    };
}));
};
```

Comment: How is `thumbs` populated? FYI, your braces don't match.

Comment: `function init()
{

if (blablabla...){

                 var thumbs=new Array();
                 thumbs=$('karusel').select('.thumbnail').toArray(); 
                 
                 
                 
                 preload(thumbs);             
                     

                 };

};`

Comment: thanks for the braces, i know about that, my mistake during copy/paste :)

Comment: Note that you can edit your own question (by pressing the 'edit' link at the bottom of it), it's usually not desirable to include multiple lines-of-code in a comment.

Comment: there's something sick in my code... probably something about event handlers... when I calls init() manually, IE8 blown out 'Stack overflow at line 0' :D

Comment: Do you have a live example, so we can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will solve your problem, but it's usually *not* a good idea to use `setAttribute` to set the source of an image element, IE (esp. < 9) might choke on that. Use direct DOM element properties instead:

```
thumbs[th].src = '/data/cache/thumb-' + filename + '.jpg';
```

---

**Update:** A stack overflow error in combination with a recursive function usually means that you're in an endless loop of recursion. In this code:

```
function loadThumb(th) {
    /* ... */
    thumbs[th].observe('load', (function (event) {
        /* ... */
        loadThumb(th + 1);
    }));
}
```

you never break out of this recursive function.

I suggest you add a condition to get out of all `loadThumb` instances, e.g.:

```
if (th < maxThumbs)
    loadThumb(th + 1);
```

Comment: thanks for correction, code changed ;) but - the core of the problem still remains... :)

Comment: ya i have this condition already... if (th<thumbs.length) i have accidently deleted that during copying code to the forum

Comment: i have tried stopObserving('load') aftre succesful loading of each item but with no effect :( m$ crap makes me mad :((

Comment: solved: IE8 is firing "load" event instantly after setting src and handler was set on next line I couldn't handle it :)